# Preload approach for stl file loading

Tags: jquery, three.js

In my scene I have 2 Mesh properties. One, of them create, the other one is from `stl` file. When I load the page, only the mesh what I created comes on visible. The next one from `stl` file not showing at all.

I understand that, it takes time to load the file and render the `mesh`. To fix that, I added a `setTimeout` function. It works well.

But what is the correct approach to call the `renderer` function after all `mesh` loaded?

Example: in jQuery I use the `$when().done()` - how to handle here?

My code:

```
$(function () {

    var scene, camera, renderer;

    var init = function () {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);

        var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
        scene.add(axes);


        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4)
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});

        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.x = -4;
        cube.position.y = 3;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        scene.add(cube);

        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

        loader.load('stl/model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.25, 0.6 );
            mesh.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
            mesh.scale.set( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add( mesh );

        } );

        setTimeout(function () {

            $('#webGL').append(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.render(scene, camera)

        }, 100)

    }

    function render () {



    }

    init();

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One correct approach are you utilizing already, the **callback function**.
The callback is executed when the loader has loaded the model, just add your renderer-call to it:

```
loader.load('stl/model.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    // this is the callback function
    // do some stuff with your model
    scene.add( mesh );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
 } );
```

In three.js there are also Loading Managers, see my other posts about preloading OBJ+MTL here: [Preloading Obj+Mtl Objects in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457314/preloading-objmtl-objects-in-three-js/31465345#31465345).

Loading with a manager:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    // this gets called after an object has been loaded
};
manager.onLoad = function () {
    // everything is loaded
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

var loader = new THREE.STLLoader( manager );

loader.load('stl/model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.25, 0.6 );
    mesh.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
    mesh.scale.set( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

Comment: As a aditional question, I am creating `stl` file using `http://www.123dapp.com/design`  after i created that, when `load` using `STLLoader` nothing appears. but i am getting the object consoled. do you have any idea to come up with this?

Comment: If you are using the code above, I dont see a light in there. Add one: ```scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xAAAAAA ) );```. If this doesnt help its better to open a new question about this new issue.

Comment: Sure let me try. the reason why i asking is, the one i am creating display correctly, and the another `loaded` not showing.

Comment: Also the usual stuff can happen: model positioned where the camera cant see it (behind or just out of the frustrum), model too big or small, camera is inside the model and you are looking at the back side of the faces... Add ```THREE.OrbitControls``` to check out your scene.